# New Search Scope

Tags: 2010, search, central-administration, search-scope, crawl

I'm creating a new search scope which is set to include all content from a specific sub site.

I am aware that I need to wait for the scheduled (or manual) update to run before the scope is ready but what I don't know is if I should also be running a full crawl once the update has taken place?  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a full crawl. This [Microsoft Support article](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Define-scopes-for-searches-65c26a72-f3d3-42ba-8027-1bf7260b6acf?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA&fromAR=1#bmha10241119_secdefinescope) only mentions the compiling/update, but does not mention a crawl.

> Search scopes and their rules are compiled on a schedule that is
>   adjusted automatically based on the frequency of past updates. The
>   administrator can also set scope updates to occur manually. A new
>   scope will not appear in a Search Box scope list until after it is
>   compiled the first time.

A crawl updates the index. A search scope is basically just a filter on the existing index, so it does not require a refresh of the existing index.

Why don't you just try it and see? If you find you need a full crawl, schedule it to run over night.